# Stop all touch detection globally?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiview

I may be onto the wrong approach to transition one view to another in a view controller, but a bug I end up having is that the view can still detect touches while fading out.

Is there a way to tell your program to stop detecting touches globally easily?

-or-

Is there a better way for me to fade from one view to another?  I expected there was a way to cache a picture of the old view, because I only need it for the effect, I don't need it to actually BE there active!

Right now a view controller method is being called, gotoIntro:

```
- (void)gotoIntro {

NSLog(@"switch to intro");

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; {
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];


    for(UIView *v in [containerView subviews]) {
        v.alpha = 0;
        v.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeView:finished:context:)];
    }

MainMenu *mainMenu = [[MainMenu alloc] init];
mainMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
[containerView insertSubview:mainMenu atIndex:0];
[mainMenu release];



} 

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}
-(void)removeView:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"VIEW REMOVED");
    [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1] removeFromSuperview];
}

The previous view is set to index 1, which I wish I didn't have to do. Sorry I couldn't put the rest of the code in that box. Stack Overflow is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents]` and `endIgnoringInteractionEvents`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

These lines will help you...

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
self.view.exclusiveTouch = NO;
```

cheers..